# Jquery resize function not working

Tags: jquery, resize

I'am trying to build left/right movement into a parallax scrolling site. Everything is working except the Resize function. The resize function seems to be resizing the entire width not just the .item that the viewport is currently on. This causes some weird shifting of the elements which gets progressively worse as you move through the elements.

Here's the JavaScript:

```
    function scrollToPosition(element) {
if (element !== undefined) {
    $(".cont").scrollTo(element, 800, {
        margin: true
    });
 }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

var posts = $('.item');
var position = 0; //Start Position
var next = $('#next');
var prev = $('#prev').hide();

next.click(function(evt) {
    //Scroll to next position
    prev.show();
    scrollToPosition(posts[position += 1]);
    if (position === posts.length - 1) {
        next.hide();
    }
});

prev.click(function(evt) {
    //Scroll to prev position    
    next.show();
    scrollToPosition(posts[position -= 1]);
    if (position === 0) {
        prev.hide();
    }
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    resizePanel();
});

});

function resizePanel() {

width = $(window).width();
height = $(window).height();

mask_width = width * $('.item').length;

$('#cont').css({width: width, height: height});
$('.item').css({width: width, height: height});
$('#mask').css({width: mask_width, height: height});

}
```

Comment: What browser did you use for testing? Not Opera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you just need to adjust the scrolling after resizing in `resizePanel()` :

```
function resizePanel(currentElement) {
    //resize items
    scrollToPosition(currentElement);
}
```

or maybe do the same effect without a timeout :

```
function resizePanel(currentElement) {
    //resize items
    $('.cont').scrollTo(currentElement, 0, {margin: true});
}
```

and update the code in your `resize` callback :

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    resizePanel( posts[position] );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'am not sure I understand where your saying to make the change? Do you mind elaborating

Comment: I tried that, but it's giving an error saying that position is not defined?

Comment: resizePanel is defined outside the scope of your variables. Give what you need to your function as an argument. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for taking pity on me.